# In middle of the ocean and can't find land

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I spawned in the middle of the ocean. I tried flying to find land, but I can't find any. Can I teleport to land, and if I can, how?

Comment: I suspect you just need to boat/swim in one direction.  (Watch the sun/moon).  You will find land eventually.

Answer (score 4):

The `spreadplayers` command will always place you on land. Try running this:

```
/spreadplayers ~ ~ 0 1000 false @p
```

If no land is found still, increase the `1000` (maxRange) and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use your map to find nearby land. Of course everything on the map won't be shown until you explored them. Try to explore the entire map to find land. Or as colorfusion said use the command `/spreadplayers ~ ~ 0 1000 false @p`. If you still can't find land and you need to find land, start another world with a different seed so there's a chance you will spawn on land. In fact, it's 90% chance you'll spawn on land so don't worry.

Answer (score -3):

Craft a boat and just keep going in one direction! You'll find land eventually. I was in your exact same situation as I spawned literally underwater in the middle of the ocean. If you have a boat, use it to your advantage and if you don't, swim, but craft one if you can. All you need is planks. I recommend turning F3 mode on so you can use the center lines to help you make sure you consistently move in one direction. In f3 mode, pay attention to the red line in the center of the screen. That's the x axis. Keep moving, going one way along the x axis to make sure you don't go in circles (a mistake i made!). Keep doing this, eventually you'll find land!

Good luck man